# LXD network lxdbr0 is "unavailable". What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: networking, lxd

When trying to create an LXD container I get:

```
$ lxc launch ubuntu:
Creating the instance
Instance name is: included-mite
Starting included-mite
Error: Failed pre-start check for device "eth0": Network "lxdbr0" unavailable on this server
```

And indeed, the network is "UNAVAILABLE":

```
$ lxc network list
+--------+----------+---------+-----------------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|  NAME  |   TYPE   | MANAGED |      IPV4       |           IPV6            | DESCRIPTION | USED BY |    STATE    |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| lxdbr0 | bridge   | YES     | 10.238.181.1/24 | fd42:10e8:9fef:5b94::1/64 |             | 5       | UNAVAILABLE |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------------+---------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

What's more, there's a warning about it too:

```
$ lxc warning list
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+-------+---------+------------------------------+
|                 UUID                 |                      TYPE                       | STATUS | SEVERITY | COUNT | PROJECT |          LAST SEEN           |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+-------+---------+------------------------------+
| 0ba1da33-d039-4e63-938b-596deba54394 | Network unavailable                             | NEW    | HIGH     | 18675 | default | Sep 11, 2023 at 3:47pm (UTC) |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+-------+---------+------------------------------+
```

And there's even more confirmation in the "status" field:

```
$ lxc network show lxdbr0
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.238.181.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv6.address: fd42:10e8:9fef:5b94::1/64
  ipv6.nat: "true"
description: ""
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
used_by:
- /1.0/instances/included-mite
- /1.0/instances/ipfs
- /1.0/instances/migrate-test
- /1.0/instances/stable-diffusion
- /1.0/profiles/default
managed: true
status: Unavailable
locations:
- none
```

The problem is, I can't find any documentation about what "unavailable" means, how it happened, or what I can do about it.

*Why* is it unavailable?  Or, how can I find out?

What steps can I take to make it available?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get the network back by shutting down LXD with `lxd shutdown` but that doesn't answer my question about what happened and how to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out *why* the network was unavailable by examining /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/lxd.log .  That was the pointer I needed.

In this case, it was reporting:

> level=error msg="Failed initializing network" err="Failed starting: The DNS and DHCP service exited prematurely: exit status 2 ("dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 10.238.181.1: Address already in use")" network=lxdbr0 project=default

and I was able to track down the culprit using

```
netstat -n -t -u -l -p | grep :53
```

which indicated that bind9 (named) was attempting to listen on all interfaces, as it does by default.  I was able to work around this by examining the addresses configured to lxdbr0 with

```
lxc network show lxdbr0
```

and excluding those addresses from bind9 in /etc/bind/named.conf.options like this:

```
listen-on { !10.238.181/24; any; };
listen-on-v6 { !fd42:10e8:9fef:5b94::/64; any; };
```

Unfortunately, you can't specify an interface name like lxdbr0, so this isn't a very elegant solution, but it has worked around my immediate problem.